# split clipboard columns and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I am a vba newbee.  Please help with this.

Here is my code so far

```
Sub Copy_and_Paste()
'
' Copy_and_Paste Macro
' Copy and Paste for test
'
'
    Windows("testv03.xlsm").Activate   
'  ActiveSheet.Paste

Dim lastRow As String

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("A" & lastRow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial

Range("G16").Select
Selection.ClearComments
End Sub
```

- please not the above code can only copy and paste from clipboard to last row

tasks performed
    1. copy 6 columns to clipboard (select and crtl+c)
    2. Then i want to paste 5 columns and all the rows to the last line in the 
    active sheet.
   3. then I want to do another paste of the 6th column next to the already 
   pasted data. this paste task has to be performed twice even though all copied 
    records line up

e.g. 
copy to clip board

```
NO_PPC  PC_92020    601000  GC.ADM.100  NO_PCO  100.41 
NO_PPC  PC_92040    601000  RA.ADM.100  NO_PCO  100.13 
NO_PPC  PC_94010    601000  FS.ADM.100  NO_PCO  100.19

then paste
NO_PPC  PC_92020    601000  GC.ADM.100  NO_PCO
NO_PPC  PC_92040    601000  RA.ADM.100  NO_PCO  
NO_PPC  PC_94010    601000  FS.ADM.100  NO_PCO

then paste 
100.41
100.13
100.19
```

The file product should look like below pasted to the last row.

```
NO_PPC  PC_92020    601000  GC.ADM.100  NO_PCO  100.41
NO_PPC  PC_92040    601000  RA.ADM.100  NO_PCO  100.13
NO_PPC  PC_94010    601000  FS.ADM.100  NO_PCO  100.19
```

Please help.
Regards
Avinesh

Comment: so you want to move the last column, and put it below the table in the same sheet. correct?

Comment: Why not take the first left half copy-paste it and then the last column seperately?

Comment: Kelaref - I want to paste it in a different sheet or workbook. the macro button that performs the paste function in in that workbook.

Comment: Blenikos - I am trying to find the most efficient use of mouse and keyboard clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely remove the need for you to copy by using (Ctrl + C), and I would do it through VBA instead, like below, this will copy columns from A:F and paste into your destination, then it will copy column G and paste in destination Column G (two separate copy/pastes):

```
Sub Copy_and_Paste()
Dim isOpen As Boolean
Dim FilePath As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
Dim wbDestination As Workbook
Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet

Set wsCopyFrom = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'above set the worksheet you are copying from
lastRow = wsCopyFrom.Cells(wsCopyFrom.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
wsCopyFrom.Range("A1:F" & lastRow).Copy
'copy Columns A to F

FilePath = "testv03.xlsm"
'replace the name of the file with its full path, such as "C:/Users/Me/Documents/testv03.xlsm"
isOpen = IsWorkBookOpen(FilePath)

If Not isOpen Then 'check if workbook is open, if not then open it
    Set wbDestination = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
End If

Set wsDestination = wbDestination.Sheets("Sheet1")
'above set the sheet you are copying into, amend as required

wsDestination.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
'Paste Columns A to F

wsCopyFrom.Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Copy
'copy Column G
wsDestination.Range("G1").PasteSpecial
'Paste Column G
End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(Name As String) As Boolean
'function to check whether workbook is open
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = Application.Workbooks.Item(Name)
    IsWorkBookOpen = (Not xWb Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: I definitely need to ctrl+C to copy to clipboard as the sections are always different. then I want the macro button to perform the paste function by pasting the first five columns of the selection to the end + 1 of the second sheet.

Comment: @AvineshBahadur when you say that the sections are always different, do they always have the same Headers? You could dynamically select specific headers through VBA?

Comment: @_Xabier - the first five columns will always exist when copied to the clipboard from copy function.  then from Column 6 to N is the second set of data.